# Checking whether UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM exists at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, function-pointers, backwards-compatibility

I am working on a universal app that should be able to run on iPad and iPhone. The Apple iPad docs say to use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` to check if I am running on iPad or iPhone, but our iPhone is 3.1.2 and will not have `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` defined. As such, this code breaks:

```
//iPhone should not be flipped upside down. iPad can have any
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  return YES; //are we on an iPad?
 } else {
  return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
 }
}
```

In Apple's [SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-1114537-BABHHJBC) they suggest doing the following to check if the function exists:

```
//iPhone should not be flipped upside down. iPad can have any
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != NULL &&
  UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  return YES; //are we on an iPad?
 } else {
  return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
 }
}
```

This works, but results in the compiler warning: "Comparison between pointer and integer." After digging around I figured out that I can make the compiler warning disappear with the following cast to `(void *)`:

```
//iPhone should not be flipped upside down. iPad can have any
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 if((void *)UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != NULL &&
  UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  return YES; //are we on an iPad?
 } else {
  return interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
 }
}
```

My question is this: Is the last code block here okay/acceptable/standard practice? I couldn't find anyone else doing something like this with quick searching which makes me wonder if I missed a gotcha or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` is a compile-time macro. It doesn't "exist" at runtime

Comment: That doesn't make this question downvote worthy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build apps for iPad against the 3.2 SDK.  As such it will build correctly, and the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro will still work.  If you want to know how/why, look it up in the docs - it is a #define, which will be understood by the compiler and compile into code that will run correctly on 3.1 (etc).

Comment: Okay, yeah, that worked. I figured out what happened: I was initially setting up the project to build two different apps and then switched over to using a universal app. The code in the first block was for the old way and I apparently never ran it when building against 3.2. Thanks for the help!